# Link Stylesheet to local html page in c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF with a browser control that points to a local HTML file.

I have my `.html` and `.css` files in a folder labelled `WebResources` but it seems no matter how I link the stylesheet in the `index.html` file the styling doesn't show.

### My Solutions Explorer

```
Solution MyProject
-- MyProject
---- Properties
---- References
---- WebResources
  ---- Index.html
  ---- Style.css
```

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="WebResources\Style.css" />
        <!-- Also Tried "<link rel="stylesheet" href="Full\Path\To\Style.css" /> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This should be very big</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Style.css

```
h1 {
    font-size: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If index.html and Style.css are in the same folder you should use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
```

I just tried with a test app and it works well.
Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't even consider that.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forward-slashes (/)? html pages usually reference other resources with these rather than Windows-style back-slashes